# Iterating NSLayoutConstraints in Swift gets "[AnyObject] does not have a member named 'Generator'" error

Tags: ios, swift

I need to iterate through the constraints on a superview of my view. view.superview.constraints is not an optional yet I'm still getting the "[AnyObject] does not have a member named 'Generator'" error. Here is my code

```
 func findViewHeightConstraint() {
    if let sv = self.view.superview {
        for constraint in sv.constraints {

        }
    }
}
```

view constraints are defined as

```
   func constraints() -> [AnyObject
```

So not optional. Trying to cast to [NSLayoutConstraints] yields the warning that it will never succeed. Any ideas for how I can iterate through view constraints using Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Very dumb mistake on my part. Auto-complete kept trying to tell me something and it was

```
 func findViewHeightConstraint() {
    if let sv = self.view.superview {
        for constraint in sv.constraints() {

        }
    }
}
```